# In ES2015 how to merge imported object into same file?

Tags: javascript, axios

I have below two files:

Api.js

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default() => {
  return axios.create({
    baseURL: '/api' 

  })
}
```

FooApi.js

```
import Api from './Api'
export default {
  foo (params) { 
    return Api().post('x/y' , params   }) 
  },
}
```

Now I want to merge above two files into single FooSingleApi.js so that Api object is defined within FooSingleApi.js file and Api.js is deleted. How to do that?

Comment: Not sure why, but I am really confused by your question? Why can't you just move the `axios.create` code into FooApi.js and be done?

Comment: It's worth noting that you can only have 1 default export per js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import axios from 'axios'

const Api = () => axios.create({ baseURL: '/api' })

export default {
  foo (params) { 
    return Api().post('x/y' , params   }) 
  },
}
```

Is this what you mean? if not, please provide more info.

Comment: karran, yes it works! I was doing the wrong way and did not put () =>